# Reference for digit dataset on scikit learn

Tags: scikit-learn, mnist

Where does the digit dataset of scikit learn comes from (sklearn.datasets.load_digits) ?
Is there any reference ?

For sure it is not the standard MNIST because the image do not have the same resolution (28x28 on MNIST, 8x8 on Scikit)

Did not find any information on the documentation:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_digits.html

Answer (score 1):

[From this doco page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/), it look like they come from `mldata.org`. What command are you using to fetch the data? From the doco there it looks like they are 28x28 if you use the command

```
>>> from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
>>> mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original', data_home=custom_data_home)
```

Comment: I am talking about : sklearn.datasets.load_digits
It is 8x8 not 28x28

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_digits.html